# koGrid - How to programatically select a row

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Does anyone know if a row in a knockoutjs based koGrid can be selected programatically?  If so, how is it done.

I would like to pre-select a row during initial layout of a MVC page view.  Hopefully, this will also trigger the grid 'selected item' viewModel property.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by select? Highlight?

Comment: Select, as in initially render the MVC page as if the user had clicked on a koGrid row to select it -- selected row highlighted, viewModel dependencies fired. Thanks.

Comment: @rjo, When multiple people are in a comment thread, use @ USERNAME to ensure get they a notification. Please post your viewModel and binding code.

Answer (score 2):

You select items in a koGrid by adding the items to the SelectedItems (or SelectedItem) object.
The item needs to be the same that is in the collection used as data.

example:

```
<div data-bind="koGrid: {data: foo, selectedItems: selected}"></div>
```

and a vm

```
var vm = {
    items = [1,2];
    selected = ko.observableArray();
}

vm.selected(vm.items);
```

this should cause all items in the grid to be selected

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the "right" way to select items, since it looks like it accessing a private field, but the following worked for me.

```
<div data-bind="koGrid: { data: itemsAvailable, selectedItems: itemsChecked}"></div>

itemsAvailable()[0].__kg_selected__(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the row with div.kgRow

Then select it by triggering the click
$(row).trigger('click');